# Simple question on maximizing a family of concave functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Given $x \in [0,1]$, let $f_k(x)$ be concave function in $x$ for all $k= 0,1,...,N$. Is the following two maximization formulations equivalent?
>   $$
> \max_{0 \le k \le N} f_k(x) =?= \max \{f_0(x), f_1(x),...,f_N(x)\}
> $$

Here is my thinking, the Left Hand Side (LHS) is to find $k=k^*$ so that maximizes $f_k(x)$. Hence, the LHS eventually gives only one function $f_{k^*}(x)$ which is concave again. But the Right Hand Side is kind of using "maximum-intersection" over the functions $\{f_0(x),...,f_N(x)\}$, so the concavity may not be preserved. Hence the LHS is not equivalent to RHS. Is this correct way to go?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your thinking is not correct; the LHS and RHS describe exactly the same function of $x$ in different ways.

The problem with your interpretation of the LHS is that *$x$ is not yet known.* It is impossible for the LHS to return just one function $f_{k^*}(x)$, because the proper choice of $k^*$ *depends* on $x$.

The two expressions are exactly equivalent. At any fixed point $x$, the value of both expressions is the maximum of the $N$ *values* $f_0(x)$, $f_1(x)$, ..., $f_N(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it !!